# How is the Geometric Phase measured in the experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, berry-pancharatnam-phase

I had read some papers that have mentioned the geometric phase (Berry phase) can be used to detect the quantum phase transitions in a quantum many-body system. My question is: How is it measured in the experiment?

Comment: The geometric phase is a phase acquired over the course of a cycle. If you take the [Aharonov Bohm effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect), you need to make an interferometer, the two "branchs" $ABD$ and $ACD$ of the "cycle" $ABDCA$ have a different phase, and so  you can see an interference pattern at $D$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But my question is how to measure the Geometric Phase, i.e., the BERRY PHASE of a quantum many-body system, rather than the AB effect. Do you have some idea about this?

Comment: Look at the chapters 5 and 6 of this [reference](http://www.theochem.unito.it/didattica/tec-comp_sdm/note1.pdf) Look also at this [presentation](http://www.dmd-sptm.it/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012_OTRANTO_1low.pdf) (Note:  The Zak phase is the Berry phase on a closed loop)

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate your own answer. I would like to read a summary of your conclusions, which would save me the time of going over the documentation you received. I am sure other readers would like too.

Answer (score 5):

At least in condensed matter systems (i.e., all solid materials you can think of), there is no direct way to measure the electronic Berry phase. What people do instead is to measure quantities which are impacted by the Berry phase (at least in the non-interacting band picture), such as quantum Hall transport coefficients [1], number and character of band crossings in photoemission [2], quantized Kerr effect [3], etc. Unfortunately, none of these are bulletproof methods, as there are many other contributions besides the Berry phase that determines these quantities.

In cold atom systems ($N\lesssim 10^{6}$, where $N$ is the number of particles), the Berry phase can be measured directly because you have fine control of the many-body wavefunction itself. This situation is unlike in solids where there are just way too many constituents ($N \sim 10^{23}$) to even talk about coherent control of the true many body wavefunction.

Coming up with a direct way to measure the Berry phase for electronic condensed matter systems is a big open question. Moreover, if you take interactions between electrons into account, it is unclear what what kinds of Berry phases are relevant and if any of them can be concretely linked to any experimental signature. The point being that the usual concept of Berry phase in condensed matter is related to the single electron picture, but that is just an approximation once electron-electron interactions are taken into account.

1. https://iopscience.iop.org/book/978-1-6817-4117-8/chapter/bk978-1-6817-4117-8ch9
2. https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/sciadv.aay2730
3. https://physics.aps.org/articles/v3/62

Comment: If a composite system (no matter how complicated) is prepared in its interacting ground state, by say lowering the temperature as much as possible, isn't it perhaps possible to vary some parameters adiabatically and measure the Berry phase? I don't see why there's a difference *experimentally* between single electron and multiple electrons. Yes, *theoretically* it would be very difficult to calculate and predict what the Berry phase should be.

Comment: @BlindMiner the point is that experimentally in condensed matter we do not have a way to generically measure the Berry phase directly (I.e. interfere the entire system with itself upon an adiabatic passage). So if you're going to look for signatures of the Berry phase indirectly, you will need some way to calculate it, which is a challenge in the Correlated electron regime (with some exceptions)

Comment: Maybe this is being a bit picky, but I don't think the number of particles in a cold atom system versus an electronic solid is that relevant, so much as the bosonic vs fermionic statistics. The results that I am aware of in this field (such as the one linked in my answer) rely on creating a Bose-Einstein condensate with macroscopic coherence. With fermions, whether 10^6 or 10^23, these techniques would not work.

Comment: @Rococo that's fair. But I guess I also had in mind the "digital" approach of using qubit gate operations to tease out the accumulated phase, in addition to using the BEC methods in your answer. Either way, I think you're right that the fermion vs Boson distinction is important - I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 2):

To add to @KFGauss answer. The anomalous Hall effect is believed to be proportional to Berry phase if I understand some of the conclusions in the 2010 review paper "Anomalous Hall Effect" correctly.

This is rather interesting as it can be easily determined if the anomalous Hall effect is zero or finite.

Answer (score 2):

The geometric phase of a topological many-body quantum system has indeed been directly measured, in ultracold atomic systems. The first demonstration of this that I am aware of is [by the Bloch group in Munich.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.0572)

There are a few variants of this experimental protocol, but the general idea is the following: first, you create a Bose-Einstein condensate in a periodic standing wave of light (an optical lattice), which gives it a band structure. The BEC will occupy the lowest energy state and thus have some definite quasimomentum. Then, you take it in a superposition of paths along the bands, which might involve driving Bloch oscillations or applying momentum kicks with Raman processes (as in [atom interferometry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/274953/in-the-context-of-atom-interferometry-how-are-pi-and-frac-pi2-pulse-g/)). Then you recombine the two parts of the superposition. Taking advantage of the macroscopic coherence of a BEC, this results in some interference with a phase that reflects the accumulated relative Berry phase between the two branches.

Comment: Can we measure the amount of the geometric phase, I mean the exact numerical number corresponds to geometrical phase?

Comment: @narip The Berry phase is not always a gauge-indepedent quantity. When it is not, there is no unique measurement of its value. However, when a Berry phase (or some combination of Berry phases) is formulated that is gauge-independent, it can be measured. In Fig. 3 and 4 of the linked paper they show such measurements, where the gauge-independent quantity is the difference of the Zak phase (which is the Berry phase for transport across the Brillouin zone) between two different dimerization configurations of the lattice.

Comment: For example, they measure a non-trivial phase of $\pi$ in the case of the SSH model (Fig. 3). In Fig. 4 they are able to vary the model and tune this topological phase.